# How to Hide UIButton in tableView after getting certain JSON response

Tags: ios, uibutton

Here in this tableView cell i have created a button i want to hide that button after getting response "1". I am doing it in following way but not working still the cell is showing the button.How would i do that.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

MyVideos *myvidoeclips = [park objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    

UILabel *lbl2=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:777];

NSString *stateus = [myvidoeclips valueForKey:@"state"];

  if([stateus  isEqual: @"0"]){

     [lbl2 setText:@"Under Moderation"];  
 }
 if([stateus  isEqual: @"1"]){

  [lbl2 setText:@"Published"];

 }
if([stateus  isEqual: @"4"]){

    [lbl2 setText:@"Rejected"];
 }
lbl2.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

// Here is my button which i want to hide


UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(216, 130, 64, 30)];
  NSString *strFlagValue = [[NSString alloc]init];

strFlagValue = [myvidoeclips valueForKey:@"state"];

if ([strFlagValue isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    flag = true;
}
else
{
    flag = false;
}

if (flag)
{
    button.hidden = true;
}
else
{
    button.hidden = false;
}




[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourEditButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     button.tag = indexPath.row;
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-details.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];


 NSLog(@"sender.tag cell is%ld ",(long)button.tag);
 }
```

Comment: can you share code with us?

Comment: @vicky - Make a different copy of required whole code out from your project, make it zip, upload on drive.google.com and share URL to download to all. so anyone can download and give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In cellForRowAtIndex check flag.

Flag will be true or false depending upon your JSON response ( Array / Dictionary )

```
BOOL flag;

NSString *strFlagValue = [[NSString alloc]init];

strFlagValue = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Key_From_You_Get_1_Or_0"];

if ([strFlagValue isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    flag = true;
}
else
{
    flag = false;
}

if (flag)
{
    cell.button.hidden = true;
}
else
{
    cell.button.hidden = false;
}
```

Also check your cell in cellForRowAtIndex must be reusable with identifier.

If you are sure to get "1" or "0" every time from JSON(Array). then below sort code is enough.

```
BOOL flag = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Key_From_You_Get_1_Or_0"] boolValue];

cell.button.hidden = flag;
```

Whole cellForRowAtIndexPath ( Logic you are writing in your question at wrong method )

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ID_CustomCell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){

    cell = (CustomCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

BOOL flag = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Key_From_You_Get_1_Or_0"] boolValue];

cell.btn1.hidden = flag;

NSString *strFlagValue = [[NSString alloc]init];

strFlagValue = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Key_From_You_Get_1_Or_0"];

if ([strFlagValue isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    flag = true;
}
else
{
    flag = false;
}

if (flag)
{
    cell.btn1.hidden = 1;
}
else
{
    cell.btn1.hidden = 0;
}


return cell;
}
```

Comment: yes the cell is reusable but how to check the flag and also i am getting the correct response as "1" only have to hide the button

Comment: when strFlagValue show "1" in console why it shows Flag=No at flat = true line @Hasya

Comment: sorry But i am confused now please update your answer and write only one final answer @Hasya

Comment: There is nothing to get confuse, at basic level i given earlier answer, if you are good at programming then 2nd answer will help obviously. put a debug pointer at debug it. No one would give you whole code that you copy / paste and use. Figure out things man.

Comment: in 2 nd answer i don't need index path i have it already @Hasya

Comment: I hope you are aware of cellForRowAtIndex.

Comment: but i am using configure cell method And i have created button there  so how would i use it in cellForRow @Hasya

Answer (score 0):

For static table cells, create an IBOutlet of UIButton and hide while checking condition using json data.

For dynamic table cells, need to identify the row number for which button needs to be hidden.

Example :- There is an array contains multiple dictionary.

```
NSDictionary* dict = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
BOOL isButtonHidden = [dict objectForKey:@"KeyName"];
cell.button.hidden = isButtonHidden
```

Hope this solution help you..Thanks

Comment: I have witten a code to create button how would i create outlet of that @Neha

Comment: You can mention it like this and connect this iboutlet to the button created in tableview cell in storyboard/xib                                                            @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cancelButton; But make sure you are using static tableview cells

Comment: no it is not Static it is custom anyway thanks of help @Neha

Comment: So it is custom, are you getting an array which contain multiple dictionaries from server??.. If yes you can hide/unhide button by writing above code in CellForRowAtIndexPath.. Here you will get dictionary from array corresponding to row number of tableview cell. When tableview reloaded, it will check the condition and hide.unhide button accordingly.